# Runner in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is script/runner?

What is a runner?

How do I use runner on a Ruby file?

What are all the commands typed out on the command prompt?

I'm using Windows by the way.

Comment: Hey, if you're reading this answer and looking for a little more info, I just published a blog post all about `rails runner` and some of the cool things we can do with it — [Skipping the console with Rails Runner](https://railsnotes.xyz/blog/skip-rails-console-with-rails-runner)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

From the [Rails Guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#bin-rails-runner):

> #### 1.7 `rails runner`
>
> `runner` runs Ruby code in the context of Rails non-interactively. For
> instance:
>
> ```
> $ rails runner "Model.long_running_method"
> ```
>
> You can also use the alias “r” to invoke the runner: `rails r`.
>
> You can specify the environment in which the runner command should
> operate using the `-e` switch.
>
> ```
> $ rails runner -e staging "Model.long_running_method"
> ```

Any code to be run must be loaded as a part of your Rails app, i.e. either in `app/` or `lib/`, among other places.

Comment: Ok, is the "long_running_method" a file which ends with the extension .rb? Also what is "script/runner", came across it in many sites.

Comment: `script/runner` is the legacy equivalent of `rails runner` from before Rails 3. `long_running_method` is not a file…it's a *method* on the class `Model`. The string passed is literally Ruby code to be run.

Comment: Ok, here is a real situation: I have Apache + Passenger + Rails application. How to configure all this that runner is started and stopped along with Apache?

Comment: I noticed that you don't need to use quotes when running this with Rails 5. Can doing it this way cause problems?

Comment: @Jake The quotes here have nothing to do with Rails (or Ruby), they are for the shell. It happens to not matter because there are no spaces (or other common shell special characters) in the argument.

Comment: how daemon the cmd?

Answer (score 22):

You can put your Ruby file into the /lib folder and execute it through:

```
rails r lib/script.rb
```

That's it.