# Pick up rails environment when running whenever

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, whenever

I need to parameterize some of my cron tasks that I'm generating with whenever by values that I usually access with the rails config gem. So I want to do something like:

```
every 2.hours do
    execute 'my/command/with/parameter #{Settings.parameter}'
end
```

When I try to do this I get:

```
config/schedule.rb:14:in `initialize': uninitialized constant Whenever::JobList::Settings (NameError)
```

So I conclude that `whenever` doesn't run in the Rails environment, which is a shame as I'd like to do some cooler stuff with it (schedule stuff based on the DB state after running `rake db:seed`, for example). Is there any way to get the `whenever` to run in the Rails context?

Answer (score 0):

Rails comes with "[runner](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-runner)" which allows a non-web-stack script to have access to the Rails app's environment and configuration. It's tailor made for this sort of task.

Comment: I'm aware of runner, but have only seen it used in the context of string representing ruby code. i.e. `bin/rails runner 'MyMode.long_running_task` like in the example you linked to. I tried executing `bin/rails runner whenever` to no effect, is there a way to point it at a script rather than a string of code?

Comment: Of course there's a point to using a script. That script inherits all the Rails configuration so it can access the DB without the need to start the entire Rails stack. I used it to write routines that'd grab data and update the DB as a cron job. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/11037753/128421

Comment: I think you mis-understood me. I understand that there's a point to it, that's exactly what I'm trying to achieve here! Ok yes, so, I see that I can set the third argument to a filepath for example and that will execute the .rb file in the rails context, great.

This example is a little more complex however, I want to run a specific ruby script from a third part gem 'whenever'. This does some kind of magic and eventually calls my config/schedule.rb file, even if I run 

    ``bin/rails runner `bundle exec which whenever```

By the time I reach my file the context is gone. Hence the problem.